# set variable as query's result in hive from hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am currently using `hue` and doing all the work through its `hive` editor, and now I want to store the result of a query inside a variable.

I know that `hiveconf` does not support this. I have seen people using `hive CLI`/ shell script to achieve it. But I don't know how to use shell script and use it to communicate with `hue` or the `HDFS`. I would prefer using a variable , if possible, instead of using a table to store the value. Would someone give me some advice?

May I know if I can do it through Oozie workflows also? Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344

Comment: Yes, I have been there. I don't know much about shell wrapper script(although I know some of cmd and powershell). I have no idea how to set it up so that can communicate with my HDFS.