# Executing query and saving result to hivevar

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

My query is `select count(1) from db.table;`. How can I execute this query and set it to `hivevar:hive_count` within a hiveql script?

Something along the lines of ...

```
> set hivevar:hive_count=(select count(1) from db.table);
> ! echo ${hivevar:hive_count}
43
```

Right now this is what happens...

```
> set hivevar:hive_count=(select count(1) from db.table);
> ! echo ${hivevar:hive_count}
(select count(1) from db.table)
```

The query is NOT executed. I want to be able to save the query result to a `hivevar` in which I can echo later

Comment: Please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344