# Looking to set a reusable variable in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm looking to set a variable like below, called `today_date`, and then be able to reuse it as a variable throughout the query. The below throws an error.

```
set today_date = date_format(date_sub(current_date, 1), 'YYYYMMdd')

select account
from table
where data_date = today_date
```

Comment: not sure what you need here.

Comment: added clarity @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: how is it being run? a script called from Beeline or Hive CLI, Hue, Ambari or something else?

Comment: I'm running it through alation. not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

First command should end with semicolon:

```
set today_date=date_format(date_sub(current_date, 1), 'YYYYMMdd');
```

And variable should be used like this:

```
select account
from table
where data_date=${hivevar:today_date};
```

set command will not calculate expression and it will be substituted as is. The resulted query will be

```
select account
from table
where data_date = date_format(date_sub(current_date, 1), 'YYYYMMdd');
```

If you want variable to be already calculated, then calculate it in a shell and pass to your Hive script like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344

Answer (score 0):

You still need to put a semicolon at the end of the `set` line, surround your variable with `${}` and use the proper namespace.

Note that this will **not** execute the `date_format()` function when the variable is defined. When you use the variable the SQL code will just be copied as-is. Think of it as more as a macro than as a variable.

Furthermore, Hive has multiple [variable namespaces](https://thisdataguy.com/2018/02/19/environment-variables-in-hive/). 
The 2 easiest options are either to be less verbose when you define your variable but to be more verbose when you use it (hiveconf namespace):

```
set today_date = date_format(date_sub(current_date, 1), 'YYYYMMdd');
select account from table where data_date = ${hiveconf:today_date};
```

or the other way round (hivevar namespace)

```
set hivevar:today_date = date_format(date_sub(current_date, 1), 'YYYYMMdd');
select account from table where data_date = ${today_date};
```