# Variables in HiveQL

Tags: variables, hive, hiveql, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

Background:

As a part of the Modernization effort, I am trying to convert a big Stored Procedure into HiveQL script. HiveQL script, as a part of hive activity, runs on Azure HDInsight cluster whenever a Pipeline is triggered from Azure Data Factory.

The stored procedure that I am trying to transform has a lot of variables declared using 'DECLARE' statements. For eg:

```
DECLARE @Variable1 INT;
```

Values in these variables are Set using SELECT statements. For eg:

```
SELECT  @Variable1 = ColumnName1 FROM Table_Name;
```

and these variables are referenced throughout the stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Some_Table where ColumeName < @Variable1
```

and many complex scenarios where subquerying is not possible.

How can I do the same in HiveQL? Is there any way to declare, modify and use variables in HiveQL script?

Answer (score 2):

`HiveQL` is not procedure language unfortunately.

You cannot use variables like this.

Variables in `HiveQL` are just text replacement, they are not calculated and being substituted as is literally.

Use some shell script or python, etc or try [HPL/SQL](http://hplsql.org/doc)

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51492264/2700344 - read for better understanding how variable substitution works in hiveql