# Manipulating hive variable

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to subtract a number from the hive variable passed. For example:

```
SET hiveconf:window_size = 12
SELECT id , max(marks) OVER(ORDER BY Date_time ROWS BETWEEN ${hiveconf:window_size}-1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) from Students;
```

But `${hiveconf:window_size}-1` in window function is giving error.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on this.

Comment: See  https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60309/working-with-variables-in-hive-hive-shell-and-beel.html

Answer (score 1):

It does not like inline calculation of ROWS BETWEEN boundary. Subtract 1 before executing query.

This will work:

```
SET hiveconf:window_size=11;
SELECT id , max(marks) OVER(ORDER BY Date_time ROWS BETWEEN ${hiveconf:window_size} PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) from Students
;
```

Alternatively you can calculate it in the shell and pass to the Hive script as a variable. See here how to pass a variable from the shell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344

Comment: Can we use a different hive variable to subtract 1 from the actual hive variable.
Eg: hiveconf:sub_one = ${hiveconf:window_size}-1

Comment: Then pass hiveconf:sub_one in ROWS BETWEEN boundary.

Comment: @RaviKiran No. Hive does not calculate variables and sustitutes them as is. So, hiveconf:sub_one in this case will be resolved to the same `${hiveconf:window_size}-1`