# How to use Hive Query results(multiple) in a variable for other query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables one is schools and one is students.I want to find all the students of a particular school.
The schema of schools is: id, name, location
and of students is :id, name, schoolId.
I wrote the following script:

```
schoolId=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false;select id from school;")
 hive -hiveconf "schoolId"="$schoolId" 

hive>select id,name from student where schoolId like  '${hiveconf:schoolId}%'
```

I dont get any result as schoolId stores all the id together.For example there are 3 schools with id: 123, 256,346
schoolId variable stores as 123 256 346 and the result is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collect_set()` with `concat_ws` to get comma delimited string, IDs should be cast to string:

```
schoolId=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false;select concat_ws('\\',\\'',collect_set(cast(id as string))) from school;");

hive -hiveconf "schoolId"="$schoolId"
```

Then use IN operator:

```
select id,name from student where schoolId in ('${hiveconf:schoolId}');
```

Comment: I got error like :  cannot recognize input near ''33992,3d1e7,68a3e,1ed4b,8aaa7,c2eb2'' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in expression specification

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman Fixed. IDs are strings, need to single-quote them in concat_ws and also quote variable in the Hive query. Also no need to cast to string

Comment: Thank you. The above procedure worked. But when I do the select query `select concat_ws('\\',\\'',collect_set(cast(id as string))) from school;` individually in hive i get an error saying  `FAILED: ParseException line 1:22 character '\' not supported here`. How do I get it right?

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman In what tool are you running it? It is something with shielding `,` - maybe you need one more slash, or single slash to shield comma

Comment: `set hiveconf:schoolId=select concat_ws('\\',\\'',collect_set(cast(id as string))) from school;
select id,name from patient where schoolId in ('${hiveconf:schoolId}');`
I tried this command within hive but again its giving me the same parse exception.

Comment: No, You cannot do it like this in Hive. Hive does not calculate variables, you can assign some string value to a variable in Hive, not query result, that is why you heed shell

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman In Hive you cannot put query result in the variable.

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman Check also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344

Comment: Actually I have to automate my work flow. I need to set the schoolId having values resulting from the query. I was thinking to put these into a file.hql and run the script.Can u suggest me how can i do it?

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53282735/2700344 Or you can use IN (select ID from school) or join w dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183612/discussion-between-vijaya-seetharaman-and-leftjoin).