# get the current date and set it to variable in order to use it as table name in HIVE

Tags: variables, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to get the current date as `YYMMDD` and then set it to variable in order to use it as table name.

Here is my code:

```
set dates= date +%Y-%m-%d;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates(
    id STRING,
    region STRING,
    city STRING)
```

But this method doesn't work, because it seems the assignments are wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive does not calculate variables, it substitutes them as is, in your case it will be exactly this string '`date +%Y-%m-%d`'. Also it is not possible to use UDF like `current_date()` in place of table name in DDL.

The solution is to calculate variable in the shell and pass it to Hive:

In the shell

```
dates=$(date +%Y_%m_%d);

hive --hivevar  date="$dates" -f myscript.hql
```

In the script:

```
use mydb; create table if not exists tab_${hivevar:date} (id int);
```

Or you can execute hive script from command line using `hive -e`, in this case variable can be substituted using shell:

```
dates=$(date +%Y_%m_%d);

hive -e "use mydb; create table if not exists tab_${dates} (id int);"
```