# passing multiple dates as a paramters to Hive query

Tags: shell, hive, parameters, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I am trying to pass a list of dates as parameter to my hive query.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing the hive query - Get distinct dates"
var=`hive -S -e "select distinct  substr(Transaction_date,0,10) from test_dev_db.TransactionUpdateTable;"`
echo $var
echo "Executing the hive query - Get the parition data"
hive -hiveconf paritionvalue=$var -e 'SELECT Product FROM test_dev_db.TransactionMainHistoryTable where tran_date in("${hiveconf:paritionvalue}");'
echo "Hive query - ends"
```

Output as:

```
Executing the hive query - Get distinct dates
2009-02-01 2009-04-01
Executing the hive query - Get the parition data

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Product1
Product1
Product1
Product1
Product1
Product1
Time taken: 0.523 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
Hive query - ends
```

It's only taking only first date as input. I would like to pass my dates as ('2009-02-01','2009-04-01')
Note:TransactionMainHistoryTable is partitioned on tran_date column with string type.

Comment: Make your output as you want in your select query itself . Append quotes and commas in your first select statement.

Comment: Is there any way to create a list or array using shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect array of distinct values using `collect_set` and concatenate it with delimiter `','`. This will produce list without outer quotes `2009-02-01','2009-04-01` and in the second script add outer quotes `'` also, or you can add them in the first query. And when executing in inline sql (-e option) you do not need to pass hiveconf variable, direct shell variable substitution will work. Use hiveconf when you are executing script from file (-f option)

Working example (use your table instead of stack):

```
date_list=$(hive -S -e "select concat_ws('\\',\\'',collect_set(substr(dt,0,10))) from (select stack (2,'2017-01', '2017-02')as dt)s ;")

hive -e "select * from (select stack (2,'2017-01', '2017-02')as dt)s where dt in ('${date_list}');"
```

Returns:

OK

```
2017-01
2017-02
Time taken: 1.221 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: @Vikrant, I did not check it, will do it a bit later, hope you got the idea. There can be some mess with quotes in my answer, maybe some shielding is necessary.

Comment: @leftjoin-- Thanks. I did bit a change to first query as select concat("'",(concat_ws("','",collect_set(substr(Transaction_date,0,10)))),"'") from test_dev_db.TransactionUpdateTable;   It's giving me output as '2009-02-01','2009-04-01'
but facing an issue while executing it through shell.

Comment: @vikrantrana fixed. I selected from stack because I do not have such table. Use your query instead,

Comment: @vikrantrana Finally have found similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53279839/2700344