# How do I insert values into a hive table in bash?

Tags: python, bash, hadoop, hive

I am writing logic in a bash script which will run hive queries and will give the result of certain validations. I need add the result in the error table from the same bash script.

Is there any bash command to insert rows into a hive table from bash script?

Comment: Is there a reason you could not have the bash script run a python script that does the heavy lifting?  Some may 'bash' me for this, but I'd rather write Python than bash, any day!

Answer (score 0):

it's butter to rewrite your code in **Python** or :
use a **python script** that gets a **query** as input, and **insert** this query in the **Hive table**, you will run the **python script** from the **bash script**

like that

```
python python_script.py query
```

in the Python script, you  will get the query like that

```
import sys
query=sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `hive -e "insert statement "` and pass parameters to the insert statement:

```
# some variables

#numeric variable
error_code=400

#string variable
error_desc="not found"

#insert into hive table    
hive -e "insert into table error_table values ('some static value', ${error_code}, '${error_description}' )"
```

You can make a function and use it with parameters

See also this answer about parameters passing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963448/2700344