# How to write subquery like: column=(select xx from table) in Hive?

Tags: hive, hql

I have a scenario, for example:

```
with tmp as (select name from table1)
select * from table2 b 
where b.name=(select max(name) from tmp)
```

However, Hive can't recognize this syntax, so is there any legal syntax for this?

After search, I learnt it can use `join` to realize:

```
select table2.* from table2
join (select max(name) as name from tmp) t2
where table2.name = t2.name
```

but I don't want to use join, as the `join` will be very slow, I just want to regard it as a  reference.
Like in `MySQL`, you are able to set the result as a reference:

```
set @max_date := select max(date) from some_table;
select * from some_other_table where date > @max_date;
```

While Hive can achieve the effect that storing query result in `shell`. Check: [HiveQL: Using query results as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206449/hiveql-using-query-results-as-variables)

Can Hive support such feature in SQL mode?

Comment: Join won't be slow and sub query is slow

Answer (score 0):

In Hive you can achieve it as below:

```
select * from table2 b 
where b.name=(select max(name) from table1)
```

**Other way :**
You can also create temporary table in hive which will help to replicate your Oracle query above.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT name FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2 b WHERE b.name=(SELECT max(name) FROM tmp);
```