# use hive variable in HiveQL

Tags: variables, hiveql, hive-query

I have a query which provides the max_processed_date (it provides a single value) and this date is used to fetch data from master_table.I am using the hivevars to do so, but it is directly substituting the query instead of first evaluating it.

```
set hivevar max_date= select max_processed_date from Tab_date where process='X';

select * from master_table where process_date > ${hivevar:max_date}
```

but this performs as `select * from master_table where process_date > select max_processed_date from Tab_date where process='X';`

which is not supported by hiveql. Is it possible that the hivevar can be evaluated first and this value can be used in the master_table query ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HiveQL: Using query results as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206449/hiveql-using-query-results-as-variables)

Comment: this would require a wrapper, this will not be possible with only hive query .

Comment: Yes. right, it is not possible with only hive query

Answer (score 0):

The answer mentioned above ([HiveQL: Using query results as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206449/hiveql-using-query-results-as-variables)) could be used to put the result of a query into a variable using a Shell script wrapper. But for your particular problem, you could do something like this:

```
select a.* 
from master_table as a,
  (select max_processed_date from Tab_date where process='X') as b
where a.process_date > b.max_processed_date;
```

Kindly note that the inner query should be 1 row, or else this will blow up the final table. A `distinct` in the select statement could resolve it, if it is necessary for the code logic.